# What is happening to the choices array in this code?

Tags: javascript

I understand that the computer is generating a random choice from the choices array, but for some reason I don't see the connection from the original choices array. Is the choices array being changed or another reference created? I just don't get it.

```
const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
let userChoice;
let computerChoice;

const generateComputerChoice = () => {
    const randomChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
    computerChoice = randomChoice;
    computerChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = 'Computer choice: ' + computerChoice;
};
```

Comment: Connection: `choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)]`

Comment: Hi, I understand that. Maybe I am not asking the question the right way.

Comment: JS scoping rules. The `choices` array used inside the function *is* the one defined outside.

Comment: Nothing is happening to the choices array,

Comment: Right, but why is the Math.floor(Math.random() inside of the array. How come it is not outside or chained to it. I think that is what is tripping me up. Thanks for the help. I am learning Javascript.

Comment: The `Math.floor(.....)` bit is just picking a random number between 0 & 2, and then using this to index into choices array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `choices` array there is just the same array, same memory address, **the exact same thing.**

The `choices[...]` means "evaluate `...`, then get the N-th index of `choices` (N = value of `...`)"

In this case, it's saying:

- Get a random decimal number between 0 and 1
- Multiply it by the # of choices
- Floor the number (2.9 => 2, etc)
- Get that index in the array

You could also write it like this:

```js
const generateComputerChoice = () => computerChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = 'Computer choice: ' + ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'][Math.floor(Math.random() * ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'].length)];
```

Yet another way of writing it is:

```js
const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

const generateComputerChoice = () => {
    let randomFloatingPoint = Math.random();
    let randomDecimalFrom0To3 = randomFloatingPoint * choices.length;
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(randomDecimalFrom0To3)
    const randomChoice = choices[randomIndex];
    computerChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = 'Computer choice: ' + randomChoice;
};
```

Comment: I mentioned above, but why is the Math.floor(Math.random() inside of the array. How come it is not outside or chained to it. I think that is what is tripping me up. Thanks for posting a reply.

Comment: The `[]` means "access that index". It's not inside of the array. Basically, it means "get a random value from that array."

Comment: ohh, just like books[i], accessing the index. I understand it now. First time seeing an array that long...Thanks

Comment: Hi Logan, Would you mind looking at this question if you get a chance. The answer from another user looks confusing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68384174/how-to-pass-item-id-in-event-listener-to-update-list-input-item/68385627#68385627