# How to pass item id in event listener to update list input item?

Tags: javascript

I have managed to build a To Do List on my own and have implemented the addTodo and add to/get from local storage functionality. I now need to add the update functionality to update a Todo list item. I understand that I first need to attach an event listener to the ul and find the closest li item id or something like that. Then I need to pass an update function to the event listener to update the input value in the list. Here is what I have so far. How would I create the event listener and update function to update a list item?

Output needed: Text of added item needs to update (to local storage) after user clicks on text and changes text of item.

Note: The snippet won't work because local storage is not allowed (as far as I know). You will need to see the [codepen](https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/QWvpLWG)

```js
// select DOM elements
const todoForm = document.querySelector('.todo-form');
const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
const todoItemsList = document.querySelector('.todo-items');

// array which stores every todo item
// each item will be an object with id, name, completed boollean
let todos = [];

// add an event listener on form
todoForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // input param from addTodo is todoInput.value
  addTodo(todoInput.value);
});

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('checkbox')) {
    if (e.target.checked) e.target.closest('.item').classList.add('checked');
    else e.target.closest('.item').classList.remove('checked');
  }
});

// todoItemsList.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
//  const taskId = e.target.item.id;
//  console.log(taskId);
// });

// todoItemsList.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
//  const taskId = e.target.closest('li').id
//  console.log(taskId)
//  // updateTask(taskId, e.target)
// })



function addTodo(input) {
  if (input !== '') {
    const todo = {
      id: Date.now(),
      name: input,
      completed: false,
    };
    todos.push(todo);
    addToLocalStorage(todos);
    todoInput.value = '';
  }
}

// todos is passed as parameter because it exists outside function environment
function renderTodos(todos) {
  // clear list
  todoItemsList.innerHTML = '';
  // run through each item inside todos
  todos.forEach((item) => {
    // checkbox
    let cb = document.createElement('input');
    cb.type = 'checkbox';
    cb.classList.add('checkbox');
    cb.checked = false;
    // delete button
    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.className = 'delete-button';
    deleteButton.innerText = 'x';
    // lists
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('item');
    li.setAttribute('data-key', item.id);
    li.appendChild(cb);
    li.append(item.name);
    li.append(deleteButton);
    todoItemsList.append(li);
  });
}

function addToLocalStorage(todos) {
  // name key 'todos" and value todos array
  // convert array to string and store it
  localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
  renderTodos(todos);
}

function getFromLocalStorage() {
  const reference = localStorage.getItem('todos');
  if (reference) {
    // converts string back to an array and store in todos array
    todos = JSON.parse(reference);
    renderTodos(todos);
  }
}

getFromLocalStorage();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: hsl(194, 100%, 70%);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.35em 1.2em;
  border: 0.1em solid hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  margin: 0 0.3em 0.3em 0;
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  border-radius: 0.12em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  color: hsl(214, 11%, 13%);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  min-width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  font-size: 3rem;
}


/* To Do Form */

.todo-form {
  margin: 40px 0px;
}

.todo-input {
  width: 250px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.todo-items {
  min-width: 350px;
  height: auto;
}


/* Item style */

.item {
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.delete-button {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: hsl(348, 93%, 56%);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  /* border-radius: 7px; */
  /* padding: 2px 5px; */
  /* margin-left: 10px; */
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 550;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.delete-button:hover {
  background: pink;
}

.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.text-container {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>To Do</h1>

  <form class="todo-form">
    <input type="text" class="todo-input" placeholder="add a todo item">
    <button type="submit" class="add=button">Add</button>
  </form>

  <ul class="todo-items">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need **ID** here. You can maintain use the index of the element to determine what todo it belongs to. Check below code

```
todoItemsList.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // Anywhere inside UL clicked

    let clickedElement = e.target;
    if (clickedElement.classList.contains('delete-button') || clickedElement.classList.contains('checkbox')) {
        // Either checkbox or delete button is clicked

        let listElement = clickedElement.parentNode;
        let listElementsArray = todoItemsList.querySelectorAll('li');
        let index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(listElementsArray, listElement);

        if (clickedElement.classList.contains('delete-button')) {
            //Delete button clicked
            listElement.remove();
            todos.splice(index, 1);
        } else if (clickedElement.classList.contains('checkbox')) {
            //Checkbox clicked
            todos[index].completed = e.target.checked;
        }

        console.log(todos);
        // Update in localstorage
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
    }
});
```

Note: Here I have used `Array.prototype.indexOf.call` instead of `listElementsArray.indexOf` because **listElementsArray** is a node list which doesn't support **indexOf** natively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this and it targets the checkbox, but not the actual list item text when clicked. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Input and click events are different. When clicking, input event won't be triggered. For listening to delete button being clicked, you must add another event listener. I have updated the code. Have a look.

Comment: Actually you can handle the whole thing in a single click event. I have updated the ans

Comment: That is way better. thanks! I ran into an issue though where the list item is editable, but the checkbox on the left is also deleted when someone deletes the text, but it should not be deleted when deleting the text. This is occurring I think because the checkbox is appended to the li item. Do you know how to fix that last thing?

Comment: I also notice you have to click twice on the list item for it to become editable. Shouldn't it become editable only after clicking once?

Comment: List items are not editable by defaut. And if you are talking about adding contentEditable attribute to the list, then thats a bad Idea, since it makes all the children editable. Try keeping an input element in the list-item. I think that will solve your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234927/discussion-between-stephenw-and-caleb-hillary).

Comment: I am curious. Are you doing the javascript course in Pirple?

Answer (score 1):

I reworked your code a bit because I was getting lost in it...

the part that interests you is at the end, with :

```
todoList.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('li input[type=checkbox], button.delete-button')) return

  let li  = target.closest('li')
    , idx = todos.findIndex(x=>x.id==li.dataset.key)
    ;    
  switch (target.tagName.toLowerCase())
    {
    case 'input':
                  todos[idx].completed = target.checked
                  break;
    case 'button':
                  todos.splice(idx, 1)
                  todoList.removeChild(li)
                  break;
    }
  todos.update_LocalStorage()
  }
```

it is an event delegation arranged to manage either the checkbox or the delete button

full code

```js
const 
  todoForm = document.querySelector('#todo-form')
, todoList = document.querySelector('#todo-items')
, todos    = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('todos') || '[]')
  ;
todos.UI_add = item =>
  {
  let li = document.createElement('li')
  li.dataset.key = item.id
  li.innerHTML   = `
    <input type="checkbox" ${item.completed ? 'checked':''} >
    <span>${item.name}</span>
    <button class="delete-button">x</button>`
  todoList.appendChild(li)
  }
todos.update_LocalStorage = _ =>
  {
  localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
  }
todoForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()

  let str = todoForm['todo-text'].value.trim()
  if (str !== '')
    {
    let item = { id: Date.now(), name:str, completed: false }
    todos.push( item ) 
    todos.UI_add( item )
    todos.update_LocalStorage()
    todoForm['todo-text'].value = ''
    todoForm['todo-text'].focus()
    }
  }
todoList.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('li input[type=checkbox], button.delete-button')) return

  let li  = target.closest('li')
    , idx = todos.findIndex(x=>x.id==li.dataset.key)
    ;    
  switch (target.tagName.toLowerCase())
    {
    case 'input':
                  todos[idx].completed = target.checked
                  break;
    case 'button':
                  todos.splice(idx, 1)
                  todoList.removeChild(li)
                  break;
    }
  todos.update_LocalStorage()
  }

// init user interface list
todos.forEach(todos.UI_add)
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

body {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: hsl(194, 100%, 70%);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }

    button  {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0.35em 1.2em;
      border: 0.1em solid hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
      margin: 0 0.3em 0.3em 0;
      background: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
      border-radius: 0.12em;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 300;
      color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
      text-align: center;
      transition: all 0.2s;
    }

    button:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
      color: hsl(214, 11%, 13%);
    }
 

.container {
  min-width      : 700px;
  display        : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  align-items    : center;
  padding        : 20px;
  }

h1 {
  color     : hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  font-size : 3rem;
}

form#todo-form {
  margin : 40px 0;
  }
form#todo-form input {
  width         : 250px;
  border        : none;
  outline       : none;
  border-radius :  5px;
  padding       : 10px;
  margin-right  : 10px;
  font-size     : 1rem;
  }

ul#todo-items {
  min-width  : 350px;
  height     : auto;
  list-style : none;
  }
ul#todo-items li {
  height           : auto;
  background-color : #fff;
  margin           : 1em;
  padding          : 10px;
  font-size        : 1.2rem;
  vertical-align   : middle;
  border-radius    : 5px;
  }

ul#todo-items li input[type=checkbox] {
  width          : 1.5em;
  height         : 1.5em;
  margin-right   : 20px;
  vertical-align : middle;
  }
.delete-button {
  display          : inline-flex;
  justify-content  : center;
  align-items      : center;
  float            : right;
  width            : 25px;
  height           : 25px;
  background-color : hsl(348, 93%, 56%);
  border           : none;
  outline          : none;
  font-size        : 0.8rem;
  font-weight      : 550;
  text-align       : center;
  vertical-align   : middle;
  }
.delete-button:hover {
  background: pink;
  }
ul#todo-items li input:checked + span {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>To Do</h1>

  <form id="todo-form">
    <input type="text" name="todo-text" placeholder="add a todo item">
    <button type="submit"> Add </button>
  </form>

  <ul id="todo-items"> </ul>
</div>
```